# Не работает таймер на Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, файловая-система, fs

```
let sec = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    if(sec = 101){
        fs.truncate('bobi.txt', err => {
            if (err) throw  err;
        });
    }else{
        fs.appendFile('bobi.txt', sec++, err => {
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

**Таймер должен каждую секунду записывать в файл число - сначала 1, потом 2, потом 3 и так далее. Как только счетчик таймера дойдет до 100 - прекратите отсчет и очистите файл.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sec = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  //let sec = 0;
  if (sec == 101){
  ...
```

Comment: Тоже самое!!!!!!!

Comment: `let sec = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    if(sec = 100){
        fs.truncate('bobi.txt', err => {
            if (err) throw  err;
        });
    }else{
        fs.appendFile('bobi.txt', sec++,'utf8', err => {
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    }
}, 1000);`